# How do you run ScalaTest tests suites in parallel in gradle?

Tags: gradle, scalatest

How do you run ScalaTest tests suites in parallel **in gradle**? I have a build.gradle that looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.7'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12',
            'org.scalatest:scalatest_2.11:3.0.0'
}
```

What do I add to make the test suites run in parallel?

**NB** There are many questions asking how you do this with SBT. SBT does it by default; gradle doesn't seem to.

Comment: How do you run your test so far ?